# Add Attribute through XSL to XML

Tags: xml, xslt, web, xhtml

I was curious if it is possible to add attributes to XHTML tags through xsl. For example, I was an if statement that if true, modifies an input checkbox field and will add a checked attribute to it. If false, it will remain unchecked.

Cheers

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a "Is this possible?" question

Comment: Yes it's possible. XSL is designed to transform XML, of which XHTML is a subset.

Comment: Yes, XSL_T_ can do that. Why don't you try to incorporate this into your code - and come back if you have a more specific question?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [ask] on how to ask questions that can actually be answered.

Answer (score 1):

This is done using XSLT's `xsl:if` statement.

For instance, if your XML has a line

```xml
<tickbox tickmark="true"/>
```

you can test the value of `tickmark` like this in your XSLT:

```xml
<input type="checkbox">
  <xsl:if test="tickbox/@tickmark!=''">
    <xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
</input>
```

using the proper XPath prefixes of course.